# javax.servlet.UnavailableException: EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap - running Struts 1.3.5 on Jetty 9.2.2

Tags: java, jetty, struts, struts-1, jetty-9

I am in the process of migrating from jetty 8.1.5 to 9.2.2. Our app uses Spring and We support some of the old struts controllers.

We use struts 1.3.5. When I start the server, I keep getting the following exception.

Does this mean, I need to migrate struts as well? Is there another solution to fix this?

I tried on java 7 and 8. Same thing happens. Please suggest.

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:399)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:535)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Incidentally, your version of struts has many [vulnerabilities in it](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-6117/Apache-Struts.html), would highly encourage you upgrade it, and maintain an active upgrade cycle with that application (especially if you run that application in the open internet)

Answer (score 0):

The class is probably missing from your war's `WEB-INF/lib`

```
EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap
```

That is the original implementation of the `ConcurrentHashMap` of what eventually became `java.util.concurrent` package in Java 1.5

Just checked 8.1.5.v20120716

```
[jetty-distribution-8.1.5.v20120716]$ find lib -name "*.jar" -exec jar -tvf {} \; |\
    grep -i edu.oswego
```

Jetty does not come with these classes (nor would it have exceptions in the `WebAppClassloader` to allow them to be used from the server Classloader)

Something else in your configuration must have added them for you.

Look for the [`backport-util-concurrent` jars](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22backport-util-concurrent%22%20AND%20a%3A%22backport-util-concurrent%22) and add them to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.